# Get rid of last (\n) symbol

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to parse a csv file, where input is enclosed in '"' and separated by comma ',' with the below code:

```
split($0,data,",")
print "\""data[1]"\",\""data[7]"\",\""data[2]
```

It should take columns separately, perform operations if needed, so don't advise to print as is ;)
So problem is the last column - its grabbed with '\n' symbol, so the next column overwrites my current line, initial file:

```
"00:00:00","87100","2381","",""," ","13"
"00:00:01","56270","0098","",""," ","37"
"00:00:01","86917","0942","",""," ","12"
```

so instead of this:

```
 "00:00:00","13","87100"
 "00:00:01","37","56270"
 "00:00:01","12","86917"
```

I'm getting this:

```
","87100"
","87100"
","87100"
```

("data[1]","data[3) is being overwritten. I have removed last column from print list, and it worked fine. And also, I can't add commas after the last column, that is too much. Any other advises on code?

Comment: it would help if you add 3-5 lines of input and show complete expected output for that particular sample - adds clarity as well as makes it easy to test solutions before answering..

Comment: @Sundeep edited, take a look please

Comment: What do you mean by 'grabbed with \n'?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/NExIAJ, it seems you may use `awk -F',' '{print $1 "," $7 "," $2}' file > outfile`

Comment: I believe you are suffering from a nasty case of `CRLF` in your input file. Have a look at [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: CSV files are only [loosely standardized](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) and I'm not sure `awk` is the tool that can actually decode them without a whole ton of dark hackery. Why not use a proper CSV parser?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting each line, you should specify the field-separator as ',' (using -F).  Then it's much simpler to print each field (still quote enclosed).  You can still access the entire line as $0.

```
awk -F',' '{print $1","$7","$2}' csv_file
```